# Trouble assigning value from cell to variable

Tags: excel, vba, types, decimal

for some reason my variables get assigned seemingly incorrect result.

```
public E0m1 as long

Set DD = Workbooks("correct path")
DD.Activate

E0m1 = DD.Range("B36").Value '(cell value is 0.5)
```

- expected result: `E0m1 = 0.5`
- what I got instead: `E0m1 = 0`

Comment: If it's a `Long`, any decimal points will be silently dropped. Declare `As Double`.

Comment: Thank you! this worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **`Long`** Data-Type **does not support float point arithmetic** *(decimal numbers)*

If you want to store a decimal number (eg `0.5` into a variable), store it into either a

- [`Single`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/single-data-type)
- [`Double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/double-data-type)

Double can contain larger more precise numbers, but from the looks of the data you provided a `Single` should be sufficient. Also, as an additional sidenote:

If you want to declare variables, unless you want to make them global for some reason, it's better to declare them with the `Dim` keyword.

eg.

```
Dim e0m1 as Single
Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("correct path")
e0m1 = ws.Range("B36")
```

Comment: Thank you, They are public because the code is made up of many subs that reference the same variables

Comment: @StevenVitale I'm pretty sure they could be handled with proper use of [arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-named-arguments-and-optional-arguments), but I'll leave that up to you. Also please, mark the answer as solved, so the question no longer stays open. Thank you :)